# Chained Payment batch - one time daily per retail partner

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

We are using Paypal Adaptive Payments in our iOS app - since we are brokering deals between consumers and our retail partners.

We need to make a one time payment to each retail partner on a daily basis - instead of numerous small amounts. 
Is there any Paypal Adaptive Payments option to batch payments?

Is there any documentation on the cost of moving money via Adaptive Payments to a bank account?

Comment: How are you currently set up in regards to what type of adaptive payment are you doing and what is your current receiver setup?

Comment: Immediate chained adaptive payments with a primary(my client) and secondary receiver(my client's retail partners).

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be a way to batch payments out without you being a receiver.  If you were a receiver (secondary would be fine), then you could apply to use MassPay and send the money you received out to the retail partners when needed. More information on MassPay can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/).